# If $x\ast y = y\ast x$ and $\gcd(o(x),o(y)) = 1$ then $o(xy) = o(x)o(y)$

Tags: group-theory, divisibility

> If $(G,\ast)$ is a group, $x,y \in G$, $x\ast y = y\ast x$, and $\gcd(o(x),o(y)) = 1$, then $o(xy) = o(x)o(y)$.

$o$ denotes the order.

I know how to begin getting details from what is given, $o(x) = x^m = e$, when $m$ is minimal.

$o(y) = y^k = e$, when $k$ is minimal.

In other words, $o(x) = m, o(y) = k, o(xy) = p$ I need to show that $p=mk$

I need to prove that $(xy)^p = x^m \cdot y^k, $when $p$ is minimal.

How to continue from here, no ideas.

Comment: So you want to prove that $p=mk$. Maybe try to prove that $p|mk$ and $mk|p$. You can prove that $p|mk$ by proving that $(xy)^{mk}=e$ and by the minimality of $p$, $p|mk$ follows. Now is it the case that $(xy)^{mk}=e$? Check it yourself. I didn't think about $mk|p$, but it should work around the same idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't used the fact that $x$ and $y$ commute yet!

Let $p = o(xy)$. Then

$$e = (xy)^p = \underbrace{(xy)(xy)\dots (xy)}_{p \text{ times}} = x^py^p.$$
So you also get that
$$e = (xy)^{pm} = \underbrace{(xy)(xy)\dots (xy)}_{pm \text{ times}} = x^{pm}y^{pm} = (x^m)^py^{pm} = e^py^{pm} = y^{pm}.$$
Since $k$ is the order of $y$, we then have that $pm$ is a multiple of $k$, or thus $k|pm$. But $\gcd(m,k) = 1$ so $k|p$. Similarly, taking the power $pk$ gives $m|p$, and since $\gcd(m,k) = 1$, you know that $mk | p$.

On the other hand, you have that
$$(xy)^{mk} = \underbrace{(xy)(xy)\dots (xy)}_{mk \text{ times}} = x^{mk}y^{mk} = (x^m)^k(y^k)^m = e^ke^m = e.$$
Hence $p | mk$.

But now we have that $mk|p$ and $p|mk$, so $mk = p$.

Comment: Perhaps add a few words why $(x^p)^{-1}=(y^p)$ implies $x^p=e$.

Comment: StreamyRoot, I think this is perfect. Thank you. btw, in the end it is "Hence, $p | mk$" I assume.

Comment: @MichaelBurr I've added a short explanation and fixed the typo - Thanks!

Comment: Steamy, can you explain how did you conclude from $gcd(m,n) = 1 \rightarrow m|p$ and what is $n$?

Comment: I made a few typos in that line, sorry! I've corrected them, hopefully things are clear now.

Comment: @SteamyRoot It makes sense now. Thank you!